# How do I get an Android device's screen size in exact pixels?

Tags: android, opengl-es2, resolution, egl

On every single android device {emulators} from ldpi to xxhdpi, both DisplayMetrics and native JNI EGL return width:320 and height:526. Even on actual HTC ONE mobile it returns something like 320x526. This is annoying. I need to know the exact pixel dimensions of the GL rendering surface {framebuffer/renderbuffer etc}. How can I do that ?

From Java activity class I am doing:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();        
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
```

From the JNI C++ code I am going following with NO luck (again output: Size = 320 x 526):

```
int W, H;
EGLDisplay display = eglGetCurrentDisplay();
EGLSurface surface = eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL_READ);
eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &W);
eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &H);

LOGI("JNIGlue.cpp:Init:EGL-Width : %d", W);
LOGI("JNIGlue.cpp:Init:EGL-Height: %d", H);

glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &W);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &H);

LOGI("JNIGlue.cpp:Init:RB-Width : %d", W);
LOGI("JNIGlue.cpp:Init:RB-Height: %d", H);
```

So how do I get the exact OpenGL rendering surface/buffer size ?

Comment: If EGL was initialized properly then eglQuerySurface should return the correct result. Any chance you have a layout xml with a scaled size that might be restricting your window resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about doing it with JNI/C++ but in Java I just query the `GLSurfaceView` for it's size with [surface.getWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29) and [surface.getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()). This provides the exact pixel dimensions of the view/surface.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you ?

```
    sp<IBinder> mainDpy = SurfaceComposerClient::getBuiltInDisplay(
                        ISurfaceComposer::eDisplayIdMain);
    DisplayInfo mainDpyInfo;
    err = SurfaceComposerClient::getDisplayInfo(mainDpy,
                                                &mainDpyInfo);
```

Essentially what we are doing here is:

1. Getting a reference to the built in display (main screen) in the form of a binder (a mechanism for IPC)
2. Then we query the display subsystem about the properties of the display that we queried in Step 1. This returns the data in the form of a structure DisplayInfo which has the following members:

   struct DisplayInfo {
   uint32_t            w;
   uint32_t            h;
   PixelFormatInfo     pixelFormatInfo;
   uint8_t             orientation;
   uint8_t             reserved[3];
   float               fps;
   float               density;
   float               xdpi;
   float               ydpi;
   };

You should have the info you require. See [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/include/ui/DisplayInfo.h#28)

Comment: Could you explain what your actually doing, here, and why it *should* work?